# Delete Google Analytics filter with Google App Scripts (delete not a function error)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I'm want to delete Google Analytics filters at view level using Google App Script and Google Analytics management API.

I'm trying to run the following function:

```
function delete_filter() {

var delete = Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.delete('213755:84538578', '123456','12345678','UA-12345678-1');

}
```

but I have the following error:

```
TypeError: Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.delete is not a function
```

Does it means that the delete function is not available with Google App Script API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? At the official document, the "Profile Filter Links: delete" method is used. But at Advanced Google services, it seems that `remove` is used. I think that the reason of your error message is due to this. So please modify as follows and testing it again.

#### From:

```
var delete = Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.delete('213755:84538578', '123456','12345678','UA-12345678-1');
```

#### To:

```
var delete = Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.remove(accountId, webPropertyId, profileId, linkId);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the returned value is void. Please be careful this.
- Please confirm whether the values of `accountId, webPropertyId, profileId, linkId` are correct.

#### Reference:

- [Profile Filter Links: delete](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileFilterLinks/delete)

Comment: Thanks. it's working. How did you know about this? What do you mean by `Advanced Google services`? Also what do you mean by `the returned value is void`?

Comment: @Simon Breton Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to answer about your additional 3 question. A1. Each parameter can be seen by the auto completion of the script editor when Google Analytics API is enabled. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services#using_autocomplete) A2. Advanced Google services is [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). From your script, I thought that Google Analytics API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services.

Comment: @Simon Breton A3. It means that `Analytics.Management.ProfileFilterLinks.remove` returns no values. This can be also known from [the official document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileFilterLinks/delete).